# How to prevent the Gmail OAuth 2.0 Playground tokens from expiring

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, nodemailer

I've followed [this tutorial](https://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html) and the emails are sent perfectly as long as the access and refresh tokens are alive

As the code should serve production how can I keep these tokes from expiring?
or how can I fetch new tokens before sending the email?

Comment: Is this for your own personal Gmail, or are you going to be asking users to connect to their Gmail your application? Google's refresh tokens don't expire unless they have been unused for 6 months (or the user has triggered a security change).

Comment: @TreyGriffith for personal use - the use case is a user contact us through a website form, the post request sends the data to the server which send it as email from my account to myself -- the token was generated through `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` and is expiring every 3500 seconds

Answer (score 3):

The OAuth Playground will automatically revoke refresh tokens after 24h. You can avoid this by specifying your own application OAuth credentials using the Configuration panel.

In order to understand how to create your own app's credentials instead of the OAuthPlayground's I suggest you follow the [Node.js Gmail API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).

The refresh token will be in the credentials object.